# S3cmd mv command not deleting source files after copying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm having a strange behavior from s3cmd.
when running mv command on multiple files in a folder (on by one), some of the files are only being copied to destination dir but not deleted from the source dir.

did anyone experienced anything like that?

thanks in advnaced,

Oren

Comment: I have the same issue. It is too bad that nobody figured that out yet.

Answer (score 0):

S3cmd first copies the object from source to dest, and then delete form source. Apparently it is doing it right (https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/S3/S3.py) and I've never had this kind of problem.

Are you running on the latest version of s3cmd?

Have you tried to run another version?

Is there some pattern related to these files you are trying to delete (ie: larger than 1GB)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some should-be-escaped characters in your files, like `(, )`, such that s3cmd can't handle them well.